# Get application URL for Azure MVC Web app for use with webhooks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I need to transer the URL of my web app to an external API. The app is an ASP.NET web app. Can I use the Azure SDKs to obtain this URL somehow?

This happens on app startup, so I do not have access to any request context.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Do you mean you need to send the base URL of your site to another system via a HTTP request? So if your site is hosted at `https://www.example.com` then you want to send that value when the site starts up...is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize UriHelper class of the HTTP Extension library, For dot net core you can find the definition here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper?view=aspnetcore-3.0

```
UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl(HttpRequest) Method
```

Returns the combined components of the request URL in a fully un-escaped form (except for the QueryString) suitable only for display. This format should not be used in HTTP headers or other HTTP operations.

```
UriHelper.GetEncodedUrl(HttpRequest) Method
```

Returns the combined components of the request URL in a fully escaped form suitable for use in HTTP headers and other HTTP operations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately not :) As stated "This happens on app startup, so I do not have access to any request context."